# Setting new sizes using JQuery does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a big table `.screens` with few smaller tables in it. The smaller tables have data, but some of this data should be optional to display. When user clicks on a checkbox "Additional data", the data should disappear, but after that, tables should be resized to keep the aspect ratio for the red bordered element (That is very important). I calculate new sizes and set it to the tables, but for some reason, an actual sizes don't get affected despite the new height is set as you can see in browser debugging. What's the problem? How do I change size of `.screensRow` as if the rows with additional data just got cut out? Here is the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/vaxobasilidze/a70ejkqm/

```js
$('#toggleData').change(function() {
       if(this.checked) {

       }
       else {
            var oldRowHeight = $('.screensRow:first-child').height();
            var minusHeight = $('.screenContainer:first-child .channelInfo').height()+$('.screenContainer:first-child .channelInfoValues').height();
            var newRowHeight = oldRowHeight-minusHeight;
            $('.channelInfo').remove();
            $('.channelInfoValues').remove();
            var rows = $('.screensRow').length;
            $('.screens').css({'height': rows*newRowHeight+'px'});
            $('.screensRow').css({'height': newRowHeight+'px'});
       }
      });
```

```css
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #2c2c2c;
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #2c2c2c 0%, #3d3d3d 37%, #353535 66%, #353535 66%, #131313 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, #2c2c2c), color-stop(37%, #3d3d3d), color-stop(66%, #353535), color-stop(66%, #353535), color-stop(100%, #131313));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #2c2c2c 0%, #3d3d3d 37%, #353535 66%, #353535 66%, #131313 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #2c2c2c 0%, #3d3d3d 37%, #353535 66%, #353535 66%, #131313 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #2c2c2c 0%, #3d3d3d 37%, #353535 66%, #353535 66%, #131313 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #2c2c2c 0%, #3d3d3d 37%, #353535 66%, #353535 66%, #131313 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#2c2c2c', endColorstr='#131313', GradientType=1);
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #b8c0c8;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

#leftDiv {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15%;
  height: 100%;
  border-right: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33);
}

#displayItems {
  min-height: auto;
  border-bottom: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 3px;
  overflow: auto;
}

#menu {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

#menu li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 2px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-top: 1px;
}

#menu li span {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  cursor: pointer;
}

#menu li ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#menu li ul li {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 250px;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin: auto;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  cursor: move;
}

#menu li ul li:first-child {
  margin-top: 2px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}

#menu li ul li:last-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom: none;
}

#settingsDiv {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 3px;
  overflow: auto;
}

#mainDiv {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 85%;
  min-height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 3px;
}

.channel {
  min-width: 250px;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #515151;
  border-radius: 6px;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33);
  box-shadow: 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-spacing: 0px;
}

.thClass {
  min-width: 150px;
  width: 102%;
  margin-left: -3px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  margin-top: -2px;
  min-height: 30px;
  max-height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 19px;
  cursor: move;
}

.header {
  margin-left: 17px;
}

.tableBody {
  display: block;
  min-height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 102%;
  margin-left: -2px;
  cursor: default;
}

.channel tbody tr td {
  display: block;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

#settingsDiv {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.settings {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.add {
  display: block;
  width: 102%;
  margin-left: -3px;
  min-height: 20px;
}

.addList {
  width: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.addList:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: antiquewhite;
}

.draggableItems {
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow-y: auto !important;
}

#displaySizes {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  max-width: 100px;
}

.disp tbody tr th {
  column-span: all;
}

.disp tbody tr td {
  display: table-cell;
}

.ui-resizable {
  position: absolute !important;
  width: 250px;
}

#mainDiv .container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}

#mainContainer {
  width: 1926px;
  height: 1086px;
}

#dispInfo {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.videoDropped {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.screens {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.channels {
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid rgba(30, 30, 30, 1);
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.channels td {
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(30, 30, 30, 1);
}

.channels td:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}

.channelHeader {
  height: 7%;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
}

.audioVideo {
  height: 79%;
}

.channelInfo {
  height: 7%;
  max-height: 7%;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(30, 30, 30, 1);
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(30, 30, 30, 1);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
}

.channelInfo td {
  border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
}

.channelInfoValues {
  height: 7%;
  max-height: 7%;
  text-align: center;
}

/*Audio styling*/

.sound {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.audiodb {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.levels {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40%;
  margin-left: 17%;
  top: 5%;
  height: 1px;
  left: 30%;
  background: silver;
  z-index: 300;
}

.level1 {
  top: 13%;
}

.level2 {
  top: 20%;
}

.level3 {
  top: 30%;
}

.level4 {
  top: 45%;
}

.level5 {
  top: 61%;
}

.level6 {
  top: 78%;
}

.level7 {
  top: 95%;
}

.audioBackground {
  width: 15%;
  height: 90%;
  left: 53%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  background: #ff0000;
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ff0000 0%, #ff0000 7%, #faff00 20%, #00ff2a 38%, #006d10 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #ff0000), color-stop(7%, #ff0000), color-stop(20%, #faff00), color-stop(38%, #00ff2a), color-stop(100%, #006d10));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ff0000 0%, #ff0000 7%, #faff00 20%, #00ff2a 38%, #006d10 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ff0000 0%, #ff0000 7%, #faff00 20%, #00ff2a 38%, #006d10 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ff0000 0%, #ff0000 7%, #faff00 20%, #00ff2a 38%, #006d10 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ff0000 0%, #ff0000 7%, #faff00 20%, #00ff2a 38%, #006d10 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ff0000', endColorstr='#006d10', GradientType=0);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.audioRight {
  left: 71%;
}

.audioCover {
  width: 200%;
  height: 30%;
  background: grey;
  margin-left: -5px;
}

.audioNumbers {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
}

.db {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 15%;
}

.db p {
  margin-top: -5px;
}

.max {
  top: 5%;
}

.high {
  top: 15%;
}

.normal {
  top: 35%;
}

.low {
  top: 95%;
}

.placeHolder {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="leftDiv">
      <input type="checkbox" id="toggleData" name="toggleData" value="toggleData" checked>
      <label for="toggleData">Additional data</label>
  </div>
  
  <div id="mainDiv">
    <div id="mainContainer" style="width: 1920px; height: 1080px;">
      <table class="screens" style="height: 100%; width: 1705.05px; position: relative; left: -2px; top: -2px;">
        <tbody>
          <tr class="screensRow">
            <td class="screenContainer" style="min-width: 850px; height: 538px;">
              <table class="channels" style="width: 850px; height: 538px; font-size: 13px; max-width: 1920px; max-height: 1080px; position: relative;" oncontextmenu="return false;">
                <tbody>
                  <tr class="channelHeader">
                    <td colspan="5" class="channelName" id="channel1">National_Geographic</td>
                    <td colspan="2" class="channelNumber">1</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="audioVideo">
                    <td colspan="5" class="vid">
                      <div class="placeHolder wideHolder" style="float: left;"></div>
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="2" class="sound">
                      <div class="audiodb">
                        <div class="audioNumbers">
                          <div class="db max level0">
                            <p style="margin-top: -6.5px;">0</p><span class="levels"></span></div>
                          <div class="db high level1">
                            <p style="margin-top: -6.5px;">-6</p><span class="levels"></span></div>
                          <div class="db level2">
                            <p style="margin-top: -6.5px;">-12</p><span class="levels"></span></div>
                          <div class="db normal level3">
                            <p style="margin-top: -6.5px;">-20</p><span class="levels"></span></div>
                          <div class="db level4">
                            <p style="margin-top: -6.5px;">-30</p><span class="levels"></span></div>
                          <div class="db level5">
                            <p style="margin-top: -6.5px;">-40</p><span class="levels"></span></div>
                          <div class="db level6">
                            <p style="margin-top: -6.5px;">-50</p><span class="levels"></span></div>
                          <div class="db low level7">
                            <p style="margin-top: -6.5px;">-60</p><span class="levels"></span></div>
                          <div class="db dbRuler">dB</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="audioBackground audioLeft">
                          <div class="audioCover" style="height: 8%;"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="audioBackground audioRight">
                          <div class="audioCover" style="height: 8%;"></div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="channelInfo">
                    <td class="resolution">Resolution</td>
                    <td class="aspect">Aspect</td>
                    <td class="fps">FPS</td>
                    <td class="vformat">V-Format</td>
                    <td class="aformat">A-Format</td>
                    <td class="leftBar">L</td>
                    <td class="rightBar">R</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="channelInfoValues">
                    <td class="resolValue">720x576</td>
                    <td class="aspectValue">20:11</td>
                    <td class="fpsValue">25</td>
                    <td class="vformatValue">HEVC</td>
                    <td class="aformatValue">MP2</td>
                    <td class="leftBarValue">---</td>
                    <td class="rightBarValue">---</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
                <div class="resize-sensor" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; overflow: hidden; z-index: -1; visibility: hidden;">
                  <div class="resize-sensor-expand" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; overflow: hidden; z-index: -1; visibility: hidden;">
                    <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; transition: 0s; width: 100000px; height: 100000px;"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; overflow: hidden; z-index: -1; visibility: hidden;">
                    <div style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; transition: 0s; width: 200%; height: 200%"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </table>
            </td>
            <td class="screenContainer" style="min-width: 850px; height: 538px;"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="screensRow">
            <td class="screenContainer" style="min-width: 850px; height: 538px;">
              <table class="channels" style="width: 850px; height: 538px; font-size: 13px; max-width: 1920px; max-height: 1080px; position: relative;" oncontextmenu="return false;">
                <tbody class="">
                  <tr class="channelHeader">
                    <td colspan="5" class="channelName" id="channel3">Nauka_2</td>
                    <td colspan="2" class="channelNumber">3</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="audioVideo">
                    <td colspan="5" class="vid">
                      <div class="placeHolder wideHolder" style="float: left;"></div>
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="2" class="sound">
                      <div class="audiodb">
                        <div class="audioNumbers">
                          <div class="db max level0">
                            <p style="margin-top: -6.5px;">0</p><span class="levels"></span></div>
                          <div class="db high level1">
                            <p style="margin-top: -6.5px;">-6</p><span class="levels"></span></div>
                          <div class="db level2">
                            <p style="margin-top: -6.5px;">-12</p><span class="levels"></span></div>
                          <div class="db normal level3">
                            <p style="margin-top: -6.5px;">-20</p><span class="levels"></span></div>
                          <div class="db level4">
                            <p style="margin-top: -6.5px;">-30</p><span class="levels"></span></div>
                          <div class="db level5">
                            <p style="margin-top: -6.5px;">-40</p><span class="levels"></span></div>
                          <div class="db level6">
                            <p style="margin-top: -6.5px;">-50</p><span class="levels"></span></div>
                          <div class="db low level7">
                            <p style="margin-top: -6.5px;">-60</p><span class="levels"></span></div>
                          <div class="db dbRuler">dB</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="audioBackground audioLeft">
                          <div class="audioCover" style="height: 8%;"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="audioBackground audioRight">
                          <div class="audioCover" style="height: 8%;"></div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="channelInfo">
                    <td class="resolution">Resolution</td>
                    <td class="aspect">Aspect</td>
                    <td class="fps">FPS</td>
                    <td class="vformat">V-Format</td>
                    <td class="aformat">A-Format</td>
                    <td class="leftBar">L</td>
                    <td class="rightBar">R</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="channelInfoValues">
                    <td class="resolValue">720x576</td>
                    <td class="aspectValue">20:11</td>
                    <td class="fpsValue">25</td>
                    <td class="vformatValue">HEVC</td>
                    <td class="aformatValue">MP2</td>
                    <td class="leftBarValue">---</td>
                    <td class="rightBarValue">---</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
                <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; overflow: hidden; z-index: -1; visibility: hidden;">
                  <div style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; overflow: hidden; z-index: -1; visibility: hidden;">
                    <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; transition: 0s; width: 100000px; height: 100000px;"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; overflow: hidden; z-index: -1; visibility: hidden;">
                    <div style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; transition: 0s; width: 200%; height: 200%"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </table>
            </td>
            <td class="screenContainer" style="min-width: 850px; height: 538px;"></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you please place minimal code that reproduces the issue? The above is a real mess to follow.

Comment: @skobaljic I have edited my code, made it as small and readable as possible. If I make it smaller, it won't help anyone to find why my code does not work. Plus, the problem should be in JS as I think... Or I'm missing something

Comment: Think the problem is `audioVideo` style that sets the height of the video, maybe do `.audioVideo { min-height: 79%; }` and also add `table { border-collapse: collapse; }`, check it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/a70ejkqm/2/). I'm really not sure if that is what you need :)

Comment: @skobaljic Same problem. The red bordered areas must not change their sizes